# Best practices for dealing with data retrieval failure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am making an application that is retrieving JSON data and placing it into a UITableView. I am just wondering what the best practice's are for dealing with failure to load data, no internet connection, etc. I have also implemented a pull to refresh on the table, so I want it to reload through that. As of right now I have everything working correctly, but it is my first time doing it so I am just wanting to see if I'm missing something.

Here is how I have it setup:

```
// Assume there are method's that retrieve the data

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self loadData];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

- (void)reloadTable
{
    [self loadData];

    if (self.jsonCodeData) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } else {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

So basically I load the data when the view load's and create/initialize a UIRefreshControl. The reloadTable method is where I implemented my answer to this question. Is that correct or is there a better way to do it? Also I am wanting there to be a filler "No Data: Pull to Refresh" type image when nothing is loaded. What is the best way to make that happen when I am using a UITableViewController? I just added another prototype cell that I marked to use for needing a refresh.

An issue that I am coming across right now is that I am having to pull to refresh twice if a user has no internet and then happen's to get it. They are having to pull it once to essentially get the data, but the if statement won't pass that time around. The next time they pull it will actually load the table.

The main point of this is just seeing if this is the best way to implement a failure on data retrieval.